# angular bootstrapping issues angular.bootstrap not working on my apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing an issue with bootstrapping my angular app, I went through a tutorial and even copied and pasted code to test the bootstrapping process, it didnt work. Can someone please tell me the simplest way to use `angular.bootstrap()` and to initialize my app with out using ng-app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/oScYFRsoCbXgpeuvN627?p=preview

The relevant bit is here (where 'test' is the name of my module):

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

Of course if you don't want to use the whole document (equivalent of putting ng-app on the  tag), you could also use jquery to find the element you wanted:

```
$('mydiv').ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap($('mydiv'), ['test']);
});
```

Comment: Can a similar action be implemented using things like ng-show and hide? I wanted to do something like apply an ng-show to an element that has a directive attached to it? with out having to go and write it, I tried actually using jquery's .attr feature to do it but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

When I simple use

`angular.bootstrap(documentGetElementById('mydiv'), ['test']);`

html element is empty and this doesn't do any affect, but when use:

`$('mydiv').ready(function() {});`

div is exist and bootstrap work as well. **All any different source say do simple:** `angular.bootstrap('html-element', ['some-module-name']);` for me it isn't working.