# Load controller after bootstrap angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, bootstrapping

I am using requirejs and angularjs to load the module inside my application.
The problem I am facing is I dont know how to load the controller after angular has been bootstrapped. Here is my code :

main.js :

```
require(['app', //all my scripts go here 
function(){
 angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

app.js :

```
define([], function(){
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
                controller : 'UserRegisterCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo : '/home'
            })
    return myApp;
})
```

controller.js

```
define(['app'], function(app){
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){});
})
```

myApp.html

```
body(ng-app)
     <div ng-controller = 'MyCtrl'></div>  <-- I can not put MyCtrl here 
because I think the MyCtrl has been declared before myApp has been bootstrapped
```

Therefore I really need to know if there is a way to load the MyCtrl controller after myApp has been bootstrapped. I am really new to Angularjs. Any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: A complex problem. Take a look at a couple of efforts, there are even more in the wild... none is complete I think: [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy), [angularAMD](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are manually bootstrapping your angular app there is no need for ng-app, because this is just a directive that pretty much does the same thing.

This little trap caused some people a headache before:

- [Why do I need to angular.bootstrap even when I declare ng-app="MyApp" in JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496599/why-do-i-need-to-angular-bootstrap-even-when-i-declare-ng-app-myapp-in-jsfiddl)
- [angular bootstrapping issues angular.bootstrap not working on my apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457957/angular-bootstrapping-issues-angular-bootstrap-not-working-on-my-apps)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ng-app` in your html, the bootstrap happens automatically.  In this case, it depends what you put in the `<script>` tag in your `index.html`.

I am assuming that you follow the RequireJS usage where you load `angular` using RequireJS.  If so, make sure you declare the dependency of `angular` to your `app` using `shim`.  If that is not the case, please state how your are loading `angular` and share the content of your `main.js`.

It was really tricky for me to get RequireJS to work with AngularJS so I created following project that helped me deal with the complexity:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD